# mongoose-unique-validator "message": "Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un cuso con mongoose, estoy intentando comprobar que un campo, el email sea unico , pero me devuelve el error que pongo arriba en el titulo.

"message": "Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null",

Este es el modelo:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

let rolesValidos = {
    values:['ADMIN_ROLE','USER_ROLE'],
    message: '{VALUE} NO ES UN roll valido'
};
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let usuarioSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'El correo es necesario']
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required:[true,'El password es obligatorio']

});
usuarioSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    let user = this;
    let userObject = user.toObject();
    delete userObject.password;
    return userObject;
}
usuarioSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{message:'{PATH} debe de ser único'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario',usuarioSchema);
```

¿Que puedo mirar?

Comment: Si no me equívoco con especificar en el campo email "unique: true," del esquema, ya basta para que te detecte que tiene que ser único el campo.

Comment: Bueno... asi lo tengo ¿no?

Comment: quitando la librería mongoose-unique-validator sigue saliendo el error ?

Comment: Pues justo acababa de descubrir que el error desaparece cuando dejo de usar esa librería. 
bueno.... con esto ya estoy contento, si me lo pones como respuesta te lo califico como mejor respuesta.
Si ademas me dices como modificar el mensaje de error, te doy las gracias. XD.

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que no da error, pero tampoco me hace la verificación...
Por alguna razón me hace la verificación en desarrollo, pero no la hace en producción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes dejar la librería de validación.
Lo único que debes hacer para que no te aparezca ese error es agregar a las opciones del **findByIdAndUpdate** el atributo `context: 'query'`.

Te quedaría algo como esto:

```js
Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updBody, {
    new: true, //devuelve el objeto actualizado
    runValidators: true, //aplica las validaciones del esquema del modelo
    context: 'query' //necesario para las disparar las validaciones de mongoose-unique-validator
}, (err, usuarioDB) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err
        });
    }

    res.json({
        ok: true,
        usuario: usuarioDB
    });
});
```

Y listo, ya no deberías de tener el problema. Esta solución la encuentras en la misma documentación de [mongoose-unique-validator](https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator#find--updates).
Al parecer, las validaciones de la librería no corren automáticamente al hacer una actuaización, por lo que las arrancamos con ese atributo.
Espero te sea útil.